# Dividir formulário para inserir em linhas diferentes da Base de dados (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, formulário

Tenho um formulário dinâmico que é preenchido conforme haja perguntas na base de dados, esse formulário tb escreve caixas de texto, checkbox, textareas, etc conforme o tipo de pergunta definido na base de dados, o problema é que ao fazer submit necessito que ele pegue cada pergunta e cada resposta e insira em linhas diferentes da base de dados, mas não estou a conseguir fazer isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora estou a fazer de forma diferente, cada conjunto de inputs que quero em linhas diferentes estão distinguidos por (name-idPergunta)

```
array(22) { ["privacidade-16"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-16"]=> string(2) "16" ["resposta-16"]=> string(14) "Vitor Bonzinho" ["privacidade-17"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-17"]=> string(2) "17" ["resposta-17"]=> string(10) "2015-10-10" ["privacidade-18"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-18"]=> string(2) "18" ["idRespostaPre-18"]=> string(2) "19" ["privacidade-19"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-19"]=> string(2) "19" ["resposta-19"]=> string(16) "Rua do mormugão" ["privacidade-20"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-20"]=> string(2) "20" ["idRespostaPre-20"]=> string(2) "38" ["privacidade-21"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-21"]=> string(2) "21" ["resposta-21"]=> string(8) "4465-213" ["privacidade-30"]=> string(1) "1" ["verificada-30"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-30"]=> string(2) "30" ["idRespostaPre-30"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "186" [1]=> string(3) "188" } }
```

Como faço para conseguir no controller separar estes conjuntos e fazer inserts um de cada x?

inserir todos os inputs que tenham -16
inserir todos os inputs que tenham -17
...
por ai em diante

Obrigado desde já

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua dificuldade? Fazer o formulário dinâmico ou fazer a query de consulta?

Comment: o formulário dinâmico já está feito, mas ao submeter quero dividir todo o formulário por grupos, ou seja, o formulário completo tem varias perguntas, cada pergunta terá resposta sejam de texto ou de escolha multipla, terá tambem um campo que diz se aquela pergunta é privada ou não e se já foi verificada ou não. mas ao fazer o submit ele envia me tudo junto e eu não estou a conseguir separar por grupos (id da pergunta, idda resposta predefinida se for checkbox, resposta se for texto, privacidade e verificada )

Answer (score 0):

Ao meu ver o seu problema é de lógica.
Se seu formulário é dinamico, certamente existe um botão para adicionar uma nova pergunta, mesmo que uma anterior ainda não tenha sido salva, correto ?

Já tive um problema parecido, eu tinha um cadastro de pessoas responsáveis por determinadas áreas na empresa, onde cada uma tem 1 nome, email, telefone e etc.

O Problema era, como identificar os dados para cada pessoa ?

Para isso criei um script JS para organizar as coisas para mim, veja como eu fiz:

Eu sabia que a pessoa tem nome, telefone e email, então temos 3 campos.
Eu preciso colocar o atributo name de cada campo de forma que eu identifique cada respectivo cliente e seus dados.

A estrutura dos campos era mais ou menos assim:

```
<div class='contato'>
   <input type='text' name='nome' />
   <input type='text' name='email' />
   <input type='text' name='telefone' />
</div>
<!-- Saber a quantidade de grupos de campos que vamos pegar no POST -->
<input type='hidden' name='qtdCampos' id='qtdCampos' value='1' />
```

Então meu script trabalhava assim:

```
function organizarCampos() {

   var i     =  0;

   var cont  =  1; 

   $( '.contato' ).find( 'input[type=text]' ).each( function () {

      //Pegando somente letras
      var name  =  $( this ).attr( 'name' ).replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, '');

      //Novo valor para o name
      var newName  += i;

      $( this ).attr( 'name', newName );

      if( cont == 3 ) {
         cont = 1;
         i++;
      }else {
         cont++;
      }

   });

}
```

Agora precisamos saber quantos campos vamos pegar no POST

```
var qtd   =  $( '.contato' ).find( 'input[type=text]' ).length / 3;

$( '#qtdCampos' ).val( qtd );
```

Agora no PHP

```
$qtdGrupos   =   $this->input->post( 'qtdCampos' );

for( $i = 0; $i < $qtdCampos; $i++ ) {
   $nome  =  $this->input->post( 'nome' . $i );
   ...
}
```

Espero ter ajudado amigo.